# Using variables as folder names in .htaccess file gives 500 internal server error

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

When a user requests `/geo/anchorage.json` from my server, I'm trying to have it provide data from `/geo/a/n/c/anchorage.json`

I have this rule written in my `.htaccess` file, but it's causing a 500 internal server error.

```
RewriteRule ^geo/((.)(.)(.).+)\.json /geo/$2/$3/$4/$1.json [QSA,L]
```

I've broken down the rule into parts, testing the first part with a php script to output the parameters, and that worked fine.

```
RewriteRule ^geo/((.)(.)(.).+)\.json /geo/test.php?2=$2&3=$3&4=$4&1=$1 [QSA,L]
```

It seems like it's the last part that's causing the error, but I can't find what I'm doing wrong. I've verified that `/geo/a/n/c/anchorage.json` exists on the server. Is there anything special when you use variables as folders?

Comment: In general: http status 500 is the message handed out to clients. Clients are not trusted, obviously, which is why you won't get much information from that message. Instead you need to take a look into your http server's error log file. That is where you can simply read what the actual issue is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resulting URL `/geo/a/n/c/anchorage.json` also matches the input regex (`^geo/((.)(.)(.).+)\.json`), so you'll get a rewrite loop (500 error). You can avoid the rewrite loop by being more specific in your regex. eg. Instead of matching any character (`.`) you could match anything that is not a slash (`[^/]`).

In other words, try the following:

```
RewriteRule ^geo/((.)([^/])([^/])[^/.]+)\.json$ /geo/$2/$3/$4/$1.json [QSA,L]
```

I left the first capturing group as a `.` (dot) since that couldn't be a slash anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You may use this rule to fix your issue:

```
RewriteRule ^(geo)/((\w)(\w)(\w).*\.json)$ $1/$3/$4/$5/$2 [NC,L]
```

There is no need to use `QSA` flag as you're not modifying query string.